# Can you Encrypt1(m), Encrypt2(E1(m), Decrypt1(E2(E1(m))) and Decrypt2(E2(m))?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

I was wondering if the following was possible.

When exchanging passwords with a server, the password should be protected. Therefore a User could Encrypt the Password with a generated Key kUser. `Encrypt(m, kUser)` resulting in the encrypted message `eU(m)`. Now the user sends this information to the server. The server now encrypts the message with its own key kServer. `Encrypt(eU(m), kServer)` resulting in `eS(eU(m))`. Now the server sends this information back, where the User now decrypts the message with his previously used key. `Decrypt(eS(eU(m), kUser)` would this result in `eS(m)` ? Would this be possbile ?

It's like imaging a suitcase with the information stored inside. The user puts his lock A on the suitcase and sends it to the server. No one can access the information but the one with the key to lock A. The server now puts a second lock B besides lock A on the suitcase and sends it back to the user. The suitcase now is locked by two locks A and B. The user then uses his key A to remove his lock A and sends the suitcase with only lock B remaining to the server. The server now removes lock B with his key B and can access the information.

How would one implement such a system (if it is possible)?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Just use TLS. Don't try to implement your own crypto.

Comment: It seems more like you've put the message a locked suitcase `eU(m)` and then - rather than adding a second lock - put *that* suitcase inside another locked suitcase `eS(eU(m))` - so even if you have the key to `eU(m)` you can't get to it to unlock it. Maybe there's funky maths out there that get around the problem, but I think that's a more accurate description?

Comment: What you describe sounds exactly like the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie–Hellman_key_exchange). And as @MadaraUchiha said, you would not implement it yourself, you would use a proven solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would this result in eS(m) ?

That depends on your decryption / encryption  function.

> Would this be possible ?

Yes. Imagine a simple Caesar or Vigenère chifre, that would certainly work.

```
  const keyA = "B";
  const keyB = "C";
  const text = "AB";

  const sent = encrypt(text, keyA); // BC
  const sendBack = encrypt(sent, keyB); // DE
  const sent2 = decrypt( sendBack, keyA); // CD
  decrypt(sent2, keyB); // AB
```

However it won't work for transpositions and other more complicated algorithms such as AES.

> How would one implement such a system (if it is possible)?

Don't. The most weak encryption is the one you invented by yourself. Instead use a library implementing the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) which does exactly what you describe, but its bulletproof (till now).

Comment: ... or don't touch DH and just use TLS.